# C# Looping int to array then counting

Tags: c#, arrays, loops, parsing, int

New to C# and can't figure out the basis on where too start with throwing the reading integers into an array, then proceeding to count the numbers in the array. Any help would be appreciated.

Format I'm following:

> Repeatedly ask the user to enter an integer between 1 and 10, or enter
>   ‘q’ to quit. Use an array to keep track of how many times each number
>   was entered. If the user enters a number below 0 or greater than 10,
>   display an error message.
>
> After the user has finished entering numbers, show a count of how many
>   times each number was entered. Do not show a count for numbers that
>   were not entered.

Example:

```
Enter an integer or ‘q’ to quit: 3
Enter an integer or ‘q’ to quit: 7
Enter an integer or ‘q’ to quit: 4
Enter an integer or ‘q’ to quit: 12
Your number must be between 1 and 10.
Enter an integer or ‘q’ to quit: 7
Enter an integer or ‘q’ to quit: 7
Enter an integer or ‘q’ to quit: 4
Enter an integer or ‘q’ to quit: q
Number Count
 3 1
 7 3
 4 2
```

My code so far:

```
int[] count = new int[10];
bool isRunning = true;

while (isRunning)
{
   Console.Write("Enter an integer or ‘q’ to quit: ");
   string input = Console.ReadLine();

   if (input == "q")
        isRunning = false;
   else if 
        //cant figure out the way to int32.TryParse here.
   else
        Console.WriteLine("Your number must be between 1 and 10.\n");
}

for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
   //Prints out number and count
}
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem? You have the numbers, and you have a counter for each one (in the numbers array)... increment the correct counter for each number entered and then output all the counters that are not zero

Comment: Your requirements don't require you to keep track of each entry - just how many times each number was entered.  Use an array of 10 "buckets" and increment the value of the appropriate bucket.

Comment: just create a List<object> and use the `.Sum()` function on the List.. with a single line of code very simple.. do a google search on `List<T>.Sum`

Comment: I would also check for `Q` _before_ parsing the input, and use `TryParse` to deal with the case where an invalid integer is entered.

Comment: current code will fail on any `input` that does not parse as `int` - so the q command would not work - consider using int.TryParse instead, or at least handle the non-numeric input first.

Comment: @MethodMan How exactly do you sum a list of objects?

Comment: @DStanley like this
`var myList = new List<string>;`
`var total = myList.Sum(x => Convert.ToInt32(x));` and you could use the `where x != to q`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your array should storage times of numbers apperance, not numbers itself.

```
int[10] Num;
while(true)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Enter an integer or ‘q’ to quit: ");
    string in = Console.ReadLine();
    if(in=="q")
    {
        break;
    }
    else if(int.Parse(in)>-1&&int.Parse(in)<11)
    {
        Num[int.parse(in)]++;
    }
    for(int i=0; i<10; i++)
    {
        if(Num[i]>0)
            Console.WriteLine(i.ToString() + " " Num[i].ToString());
    }
}
```

Comment: Valid numbers range from 1 to 10, so you're missing a `-1` or two...

Comment: You are on the correct path, but, parsing 3 times the same data? And what if I type Z instead of q. Int.Parse will throw

Comment: As in task user is asked for numbers from 1 to 10 and char 'q' not anything else. No one asked to check exeptions. But with parsing 3 times i agreed. Just too lazy to create new varible).

Comment: @G0867532 fine, but quality answers keep an open eye on the problems lurking in the OP code.

Comment: If you plan to answer to "write my homework" question please make sure to post good code that compiles with nice explanations. Also make sure to answer all points in the question...